# Appium can't find 'appPackage' parameter

Tags: android, ruby, linux, selenium, appium

I'm trying to run simple RSpec test on real Android device using Appium. My config is:

```
apk = {
    device: :android,
    app_path: *path_to_apk*,
    app_package: *app_package*,
    app_activity: '.Start'
}
```

Then I'm starting driver by:

```
Appium::Driver.new(apk).start_driver
```

Script fails with error:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Parameter 'appActivity' is
>   required for launching application

I tried to debug by steps and found out, that in `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default` inside `request` method script sends post request with path: `"/wd/hub/session"` and body: `{"desiredCapabilities":{"platform":"OS X 10.9","platformName":"android","name":"Ruby Console iOS Appium","device-orientation":"portrait","app":*path_to_apk*}}`. The response is HTTPInternalServerError object with body:

> "{   "status": 33,   "value": {
>       "message": "A new session could not be created. (Original error: Parameter 'appActivity' is required for launching application)",
>       "origValue": "Parameter 'appActivity' is required for launching application"   },   "sessionId": null }"

I can't understand what's the problem and find any solutions in google. Maybe value of `'app_package'` parameter is wrong? So my second question is how can I get it?

P.S. Before all, appium was run in terminal by command `appium &` and started successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How to get app package?

   Answer: Open 'Dev Tools' in emulator/device, then go to package browser then select your application , there you will get the app package along with available activities.
2. What is the problem with your code:

   Ensure to include these stuffs:

   platformName: 'Android',

   appActivity: '.activity_name',

   appPackage: 'package_name'